# Direct Website to other internal pages like sales, products page in client side

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, web, controls

How I can control my website in client side and remotely redirect and change the pages of my site in the client browser, So I can show him our sales and products while he is on index page?

[CLIENT]--view my index page---> {I can direct him to Sales page from my end}

Is there any way to do it in Jquery or HTML5, I just need a lead and I will keep going. I tried Google but I was unlucky.

Regards
Oto

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible in real time, but with accepting some delay you could use ajax to load your last commands every second or two. You could integrate a remote function that connects every few seconds to the server to get new commands after the user clicks on a button and inserts a auth code. But why don't you want to use something like teamviewer? Its small and handy.
http://www.teamviewer.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, I am not planning to do a remote access, I just want to redirect the browser to some other pages like sales and productions.

See its like I am working now on adding comments and you redirect the site to me to "Blog page" for example.

Comment: But you want to redirect in the moment you publish the comment? So everybody on your site can see the new comment?